# How To Read Multiple Calendar Dates Pikaday

Tags: javascript, pikaday

I have two calendars -- a calendar that selects From a date and another one that selects To a date -- that I have built with [Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday). During my `onSelect` event I would like to get the dates of both calendars so that I can use jQuery to filter a list of items based on the selected date range of both calendars. I've read through the documentation but I can see no way other via the Pikaday API to read both selected dates on my two calendars.

Has anyone been able to use Pikday such that during an `onSelect` event they can read the selected dates from their calendars?

Comment: Save your Pikaday objects into a variable that has the appropriate scope to be accessed from your event, then get the value with `.getMoment()`

Answer (score 0):

Either read the input of both fields specified in the pickaday config or listen for changes and store the date for later use.

```
var date1 = new Pickaday({
  field: $('input#my-first-field')
});
var date2 = new Pickaday({
  field: $('input#my-second-field')
});

// in your onSelect:
date1.toString(optionalFormattingParameter);
date2.toString(optionalFormattingParameter);
```

`.toString()` of pickaday objects can also be used within your `onSelect`
More information: https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday#get-and-set-date